# How to write multiple count select statement in sql

Tags: sql, select, count

I need to combine the two count statement into one select. can this be done?

```
select dealer
,firstname
,ProductType
,date
,Comments
,COUNT(*) as Total
select dealer
,firstname
,Valid
,Comments
,COUNT(*) as InvalidTotal
```

Comment: how do you determine if a filed is `valid` or `invalid`?

Comment: what is the whole select statement?

Comment: you mentioned two count statements, where is the other one ??

Answer (score 0):

You could use a UNION statement to create a single query, which will return two rows. Howwever, the column name for the count(*) column will come from the first query, so you could add a flag, such as the IsValid column in the example below

```
  select VR.Dealerid
    ,VR.commissionrunid
    ,VD.ProductType
    ,VD.Valid
    ,VD.Comments,
    1 as IsValid,
    ,COUNT(*) as Total
    UNION ALL
    select VR.Dealerid
    ,VR.commissionrunid
    ,VD.Valid
    ,VD.Comments
    0 as IsValid,
    ,COUNT(*) as InvalidTotal
```

**However, if you are looking for one row, i.e.**

```
  select VR.Dealerid
    ,VR.commissionrunid
    ,VD.ProductType
    ,VD.Valid
    ,VD.Comments,
    ,COUNT(*) as Total
    ,COUNT(*) as InvalidTotal.
```

Then we need to see how you determine Valid vs Invalid for counting purposes.   It is definitely doable, you need to create a CASE statement that returns 1 or 0 (for valid or invalid) and SUM those columns.    Without knowing your SQL dialect, the following is a pseudo-code representation..

```
SUM (CASE isValid='Y' then 1 else 0 END) as TotalValid,
SUM (CASE isValid='N' then 1 else 0 END) as TotalInValid,
```